# The programs quits before printing the last lines

Tags: c, printf

The program finishes before printing the last lines before returning the value 0, it doesn't print the ones I marked with `/* ** */`:

```
int main()
{
        int num,sum=0,num1;
        printf("Enter size of input:\n");
        scanf("%d",&num);

        int *arr=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*num);
        printf("Enter numbers:\n");
        for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
        {
            if(scanf("%d", &num1))
            {
                arr[i]=num1;
                sum+=powerOfTwo(num1);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Invalid number");  /* ** */
                free(arr);
                printf("\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
        {
            printf("The number %d is a power of 2: %d = 2^%d\n", arr[i], arr[i], powerOfTwo(arr[i]));
        }
        printf("Total exponent sum is %d\n",sum); /* ** */

        free(arr);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: **  printf("Total exponent sum is %d\n",sum); 
^^ Why are there " ** " there??

Comment: You're not checking for *any* errors.  What does `scanf()` return?  Did `malloc()` actually work?

Comment: I checked them but removed them from this code @AndrewHenle

Comment: @proneon just to show you guys which lines didn't work

Comment: what is the powerOfTwo(); function??I mean does it return the power of 2 to the given number??

Comment: @proneon yeah it works

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/HkOv6mt5f
I don't see the problem.

Comment: Ok. Hope you got what you want.

Comment: It would be more conventional to `return 1;` or `return EXIT_FAILURE;` (or use `exit()` with one of those values) to indicate that the program failed.  Using `return 0;` (or `EXIT_SUCCESS`) indicates that the program succeeded.  Error messages should be written to standard error, not standard output, too.  However, that's not a cause of your problem.

Comment: I ran this (with my own powerOfTwo), and it worked fine.

In a situation like this, it helps if you post code that can be built and run as-is, including the #include statements. That way at least the problem can be verified, and a certain class of problem can be ruled out.

Also, you have the printf variables in the wrong logical order.

You want <code>printf("The number %d is a power of 2: %d = 2^%d\n", arr[i], powerOfTwo(arr[i]), arr[i]);</code>